# how to split a long text from database to show it as different paragraphs in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string with line breaks in my database,i want to split this and show it as paragraphs in my web page
here is my text in my database:

```
My first paragraph my second paragraph my third paragraph
```

I want to show this in my web page as

```
My first paragraph
my second paragraph
my third paragraph
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?
$str = 'My first paragraph my second paragraph my third paragraph';

$newstr = str_replace('\n','<br>',$str);

echo $newstr;
?>
```

Comment: Where paragraphs are actual paragraphs, it's probably best - semantically - to mark up the text with the `<p>` tag though right?

Answer (score 0):

Php actually has a function for this: `nl2br`. So you can say `echo nl2br($str);`